# How to safely control Thinkpad Fan? Who has bought a Thinkpad with preinstalled Ubuntu?

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, fan, fancontrol

I have a new Thinkpad and the fan is permanently running and it is impossible to use the machine although there is less than 10% processor consumption. The noise of Ubuntu is annoying. In Windows I just adjust in the Power Options the System Cooling Policy from active to passive and the fan is quite. No further thinking is necessary. Why it cannot be so easy for Ubuntu?
For Ubuntu I am searching the internet for already some days and I find only do it yourself solutions for tinkerers. There is an utility called Thinkfan without GUI that seems to be dangerous to use:

> ## WARNING!!!!
>
> There's only very basic sanity checking on the configuration (semantic plausibility). You can set the temperature limits as insane as you like.
>   Any change to fan behaviour that results in higher temperatures in some parts of the system will shorten your system's lifetime and/or cause weird hardware bugs that'll make you pull out your hair.
>     No warranties whatsoever.
>   If this program steals your car, kills your horse, smokes your dope or pees on your carpet...  - too bad, you're on your own.
>   [Link](https://github.com/vmatare/thinkfan)

It is quite dangerous to modify the temperatures. There is even a

> -D DANGEROUS mode: Disable all sanity checks. May damage your hardware!! [Link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/thinkfan.1.html)

The program has a complicated configuration file that has to be modified by the user. How can I be sure that the modification of the file that I make is correctly understood by the program? Maybe a space less or more or mixing up a semicolon with a comma or a wrong bracket and I suffer eternal perdition? Before I start to modify the file I would also like to know which settings or which range of settings can I use for my special notebook. Destroying your own computer by eagerly optimizing some parameters is a realistic scenario regarding the warnings above. The best would be a ready-made configuration file. The fan noise shall be as quite as possible. Lenovo sells Thinkpad laptops with preinstalled Ubuntu. The best help would come from somebody who has bought from Lenovo a laptop with preinstalled Ubuntu. The preinstalled Ubuntu is for certain configured by Lenovo. Maybe another fan control program is available from the preinstalled laptops. So a complicated way to be safe.

I have a ThinkPad P1 Gen 2 with  Intel Core i7-9750H with Ubuntu 19.10 that was not preinstalled.

Comment: Sometimes there is no ready made and tested solution, especially if the hardware is new, and there is no vendor support. Usually it gets better with time, as kernel devs and tinkerers work out solutions. I don't know if Lenovo has that model preinstalled or tested with Ubuntu. If you know that is the case, ask Lenovo for config files.